# MS Excel Date/Time Difference

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I am trying to determine the time difference using two fields that contain a Date/Time stamp. The Date and Time are separated by a 'T'. I'd like the final answer to be converted into a decimal representing the total time. Example: 1.3 days. I've tried a couple of approached with minimal success. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Created Date/Time   Resolved Date/Time
2016-11-30T10:31:25 2016-11-30T10:33:40
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the `T` with a `" "`.  Then subtract the one from the other:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B2,"T"," ")-SUBSTITUTE(A2,"T"," ")
```

Then Use the following custom format: `0.0#### \d\a\y\s`

[image]